# How to Display time on lock screen?

Tags: htc

I accidentally unpin the time on my phone lock screen and now I don't know how to pin it back. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The special time and weather app that comes with the HTC 8X and HTC 8S is available from the [App list](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp8/basics/wheres-the-app-list)...

1. Swipe left on the Start menu and you should see it
2. Then tap and hold, and a menu will appear - choose **Pin to start**.

If the App has been deleted, go to the [Store app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp8/apps/get-apps-from-the-store) and look in the HTC section, you should be able to download the app again.